# In a graph without cycles, does the sequence of a path matter?

Tags: graph-theory

Assume we have a cycle-free graph G and and a walk, which is a finite sequence of edges $n$ $e_1=(a_1,b_1),e_2=(a_2,b_2),\dots,e_n=(a_n,b_n)$ with $b_i = a_{i+1}$ and a fix start point $p = a_1$.

If I would mix up the edges, and build up my own path that starts at $a_1$, can I be sure that I finally will end in $b_n$? Meaning, the last edge is $(?,b_n)$?

With building my own path I mean I start with an edge starting in $a$ and I add up any edge, as long as there is a possible edge to add (the new path could be shorter).

After looking at varies examples, it looks almost obvious to me, but I cannot prove it.

I tried to do induction. The induction start is clear, and for the induction step I came here:

Assume we have $n+1$ edges $e_i=(a_i,b_i)$. Now take any edge $e_j$ with $a_j=a$.

**Case 1**: There exists only one edge with $a_j = a$, then we have to take it, and  by induction hypothesis we are done.

Now lets consider the scenario that we have multiple edges starting in `a`,

**Case 2**: There is no edge back, i.e. there exist no edge $(b_j, a)$. Since the graph is cycle-free, we will never reach any of the edges $e_i, i<j$. We can conclude that $e_1,\dots,e_{j-1}$ is a path that starts at $a$ and returns at $a$. Thus, the question is, if a mix from $e_{j+1},\dots,e_{n+1}$ will lead to $b_{n+1}$ and this follows by induction hypothesis.

**Case 3**: I don't really know how to argue here.

Can anyone help me out how to finish this? Or is there a even simpler solution without induction?

Comment: If for example your edges are $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$, and $(2,4)$, can't you end up taking edges $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$ and never reach $4$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov good catch! I forgot to mention that the sequence of edges must form one valid path. I added it to the question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. A path by definition does not visit any vertex more than once, so there is no way to "mix up" the edges of a path. If you do allow vertices to be visited more than once, it is called a walk. If you consider the subgraph consisting only of the edges of a walk, and the start and end are distinct vertices, then the start and end vertices are the only ones of odd degree. It is not possible to "get stuck" at any vertex with an even degree as there will always be an odd (hence non-zero) number of unused edges leading from it whenever you reach such a vertex.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis sorry, in this case I do mean a walk, not a path. I am not well-read in graph theory. - Very nice proof with the even degree. Makes sense, and I can throw away my induction solution

Comment: @JaapScherphuis do you think the statement is wrong if start and end point can be the same=

Comment: @Adam No, it still works in that case too. You also don't need the graph to be acyclic.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis and how would you proof that?

Comment: You can prove it exactly the same way. Nowhere does the proof make use the fact that the graph is acyclic. BTW, I have assumed the graph is undirected. For directed graphs the same proof works if instead of "vertices of even degree" you read "vertices with in-degree equal to out-degree".

Comment: @JaapScherphuis if the graph is not directed, then I don't think you can conclude that the number of edges for start & end node is odd (I can draw you a counter example). Its true, your proof does not need acyclic property, but it assumes start and end are not equal. If they are equal, I cannot see how one can guarantee that every walk with max number of edges will end in $b_n$

Comment: I skipped some details: Construct the graph consisting of only the edges used in the walk. **If the walk traverses an edge multiple times, include that edge that same number of times in this graph.** The walk therefore traverses all the edges in this graph exactly once. It is a [Eulerian walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path). Such a graph has even degree vertices, except possibly for the start/end vertices of the walk, and then only if they differ. If you start a new walk, deleting each edge you traverse, the only vertices of odd degree are your current one and the final vertex.